# How to remove the space at the end of some value in postman and then save the response in some variable?

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a json response where some values have spaces at the end.

I am doing a response comparison of one API with other where one API has correct value and other has space at end hence my comparison logic returns its a mismatch. I want to skip such mismatches in my comparison.

I want to remove the spaces from two keys only in whole json response.

Part of actual response. Please note its an array response and has 380 elements in array.

```
[
    {
        "term": 1,
        "monthlyCost": 15.0,
        "totalMinimumCost": 15.0,
        "shortDescription": "$10 International Value Pack ",
        "displayName": "$10 International Value Pack ",
        "longDescription": "Includes Infinite standard TXT here and to overseas.",
        "displayPriority": 4,
        "externalSkuId": "NA",
        "auxiliaryMedia": {
            "T&CContent": "Please read the terms and conditions <a href=\"http://URL/csFreeModule\"  target=\"_blank\">here</a>."
        },
        "inclusions": "Infinite national and international TXT",
        "parentProduct": "prod514df70mdl4",
        "id": "sku1347dfg0491mdl4"
    },
    {
        "term": 1,
        "monthlyCost": 30.0,
        "totalMinimumCost": 30.0,
        "shortDescription": "7GB Data Add-on",
        "displayName": "$30 7GB Data Add-on Month to Month",
        "longDescription": "Includes data to use on your mobile phone within country.\rAny additional data use will be charged as per the applicable additional data rate for your plan product – refer to your specific plan’s additional data charge rate for details. ",
        "displayPriority": 1,
        "externalSkuId": "AUD0450",
        "auxiliaryMedia": {
            "T&CContent": "<p><strong>Data Add-on $30 for 7GB</strong></p>\r<p>This Add-on costs $30 per month and includes 7GB of data (equals $0.0042/MB) to use in country.</p> <p>Only available to customers connected to eligible voice plans. Personal use only. Data expires after 1 month. Minimum monthly spend is $30. Recurring monthly access fee charged until the end of the month in which you cancel. Data deducted in per KB increments. Once you exhaust your Add-on’s Included Data, any further data usage will be deducted from your voice plan’s Included Data (if any). Thereafter, it will be charged at the additional data rate of your voice plan – refer to your plan for details. Add-on will be cancelled if there is no longer an active voice plan on your account. Min monthly spend is not prorated when Add-On is purchased or cancelled part way through the billing month. If provisioned on an account which supports data sharing, included data is shareable across the group.</p>\r \r\r<p>Companu Pty Ltd ABN 76 062 954 554.</p>\r</div>\r"
        },
        "inclusions": "7GB",
        "parentProduct": "prod5170040stgvha",
        "cisInfo": "http://URL/july-17.pdf",
        "id": "sku13511we376stgvha"
    }
]
```

I have used below code which works but can someone guide me how to make Regex more efficient? Rather than mentioning the exact string how can I only remove space from end as in future more garbage data like this is expected.

```
var responseData = JSON.stringify(responseBody);
var noSpacesString= responseData.replace(/\$10 International Value Pack /g,'$10 International Value Pack');;// remove space from end
console.log(JSON.parse(noSpacesString));
```

I want to remove the space in end of "Pack" of "shortDescription" and "displayName". After that I need to store it as JSON in some variable to do the comparison with other API. How to do this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove spaces at the start and the end of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response of type string, parse it using `JSON.parse` and for each item in the response call a function which trims strings in that object. You canuse [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```js
const response = [
{
    term: 1,
    monthlyCost: 15.0,
    totalMinimumCost: 15.0,
    shortDescription: "$10 International Value Pack ",
    displayName: "$10 International Value Pack ",
    longDescription: "Includes Infinite standard TXT here and to overseas.",
    displayPriority: 4,
    externalSkuId: "NA",
    auxiliaryMedia: {
    "T&CContent":
        'Please read the terms and conditions <a href="http://URL/csFreeModule"  target="_blank">here</a>.',
    },
    inclusions: "Infinite national and international TXT",
    parentProduct: "prod514df70mdl4",
    id: "sku1347dfg0491mdl4",
},
{
    term: 1,
    monthlyCost: 30.0,
    totalMinimumCost: 30.0,
    shortDescription: "7GB Data Add-on",
    displayName: "$30 7GB Data Add-on Month to Month",
    longDescription:
    "Includes data to use on your mobile phone within country.\rAny additional data use will be charged as per the applicable additional data rate for your plan product – refer to your specific plan’s additional data charge rate for details. ",
    displayPriority: 1,
    externalSkuId: "AUD0450",
    auxiliaryMedia: {
    "T&CContent":
        "<p><strong>Data Add-on $30 for 7GB</strong></p>\r<p>This Add-on costs $30 per month and includes 7GB of data (equals $0.0042/MB) to use in country.</p> <p>Only available to customers connected to eligible voice plans. Personal use only. Data expires after 1 month. Minimum monthly spend is $30. Recurring monthly access fee charged until the end of the month in which you cancel. Data deducted in per KB increments. Once you exhaust your Add-on’s Included Data, any further data usage will be deducted from your voice plan’s Included Data (if any). Thereafter, it will be charged at the additional data rate of your voice plan – refer to your plan for details. Add-on will be cancelled if there is no longer an active voice plan on your account. Min monthly spend is not prorated when Add-On is purchased or cancelled part way through the billing month. If provisioned on an account which supports data sharing, included data is shareable across the group.</p>\r \r\r<p>Companu Pty Ltd ABN 76 062 954 554.</p>\r</div>\r",
    },
    inclusions: "7GB",
    parentProduct: "prod5170040stgvha",
    cisInfo: "http://URL/july-17.pdf",
    id: "sku13511we376stgvha",
},
];

const trimSpaces = (obj) => {
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "string") obj[key] = obj[key].trim();
});
};

response.forEach(trimSpaces);

console.log(response);
```

Comment: Thanks Abito this code works. But actually my JSON response if quite big and its array of result. I am getting JSON response in a variable and how to trim from here. I tried above code with json variable below but it failed. 

var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);

As JSON response of API is huge I have to store it in a variable

Comment: Can you please post some part of the JSON response in the question so that I can understand the structure and provide an appropriate answer

Comment: I have added the partial response. Please have a look. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Maddy Please check now, let me know if it is not working

Comment: Thank you so much @Abito it worked perfectly. This is exactly what I was looking for.